# Reverse proxy capable pure python webserver?

Tags: python, proxy, webserver, reverse

I am looking for a pure python based web server has the capability for reverse proxy as well?

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852690/reverse-proxy-capable-pure-python-webserver

Answer (score 2):

pretty sure you can do that with twisted,

[twisted web](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb)

but why not just use apache?