# Reverse proxy capable pure python webserver?

Tags: python, proxy, webserver, reverse

I am looking for a pure python based web server has the capability for reverse proxy as well?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/), especially its [ReverseProxyResource](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.proxy.ReverseProxyResource.html).

> Twisted Web also provides various facilities for being set up behind a reverse-proxy, which is the suggested mechanism to integrate your Twisted application with an existing site.

Answer (score 0):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/proxylet/

From http://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/proxylet-lightweight-HTTP-reverse-proxy

> proxylet is a lightweight reverse proxy for HTTP with nonblocking IO courtesy of eventlet.

Looks like source is available as well.  I've never used it, as we use [IHS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/httpservers/) for all our reverse proxy needs.

Comment: I don't know if proxtlet would be a good choice as it is bringing misc third party dependencies (paste, eventlets, greenlets etc)

I tried your suggested link on jaunty (ubuntu). The example code in the __init__.py under proxylet-0.1.1/proxylet didn't work.