# Pure python reverse proxy that handles chunking

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.internet

[Reverse proxy capable pure python webserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852690/reverse-proxy-capable-pure-python-webserver)

References `twisted`, and there is a great example for how to set up a reverse proxy, that appears to work. I could not find how to make the example collect all the chunks and send off an unchunked request to the upstream server, like happens with the default `nginx` reverse proxy config. Is that possible with `twisted`? Some other pure python project?

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server

site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('localhost', 8002, b''))
reactor.listenTCP(8081, site)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Twisted has code to handle chunks, so you could probably watch for `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and process accordingly. The 'cheating way' I've seen other proxies use is to explicitly set the request protocol to `HTTP/1.0` so that chunking never happens.

Comment: Alas, I don't control the clients and am reproducing a proprietary API that only does 1.1+